How can Windows Security quarantine detected files but not delete them?
I would like to quarantine detected files before they get deleted but the system admin must have enforced some group policies as I am not allowed to find any quarantine-related settings in Windows Security. I have full access to the Group Policy editor. I would like to know which policies I need to set Windows Security to quarantine detected files before deleting them.

It depends on the detection actually. Microsoft will straight out delete certain files instead of quarantining them, especially if it are products that can be used to pirate windows.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
